when can a pair of module be quotients of each other?
I'm interested in the Schröder–Bernstein property (i.e., if $A$ and $B$ can be embedded into each other, then $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic) and similar properties in various contexts.
I already know that groups, rings, and fields lack the Schröder–Bernstein property. Now I’m curious about whether this property fails when we consider "quotients" instead of "embeddings" (i.e., if there are surjective morphisms $A\rightarrow B$ and $B\rightarrow A$, $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic). I have found counterexamples in groups ($\mathbb{ℤ}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ and $\mathbb{ℤ}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}\oplus(\mathbb{ℤ}/2\mathbb{ℤ})$) and rings ($\mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2,\ldots]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2,\ldots]/(x_1^2)$). I believe there may also be a counterexample in the context of $R$-modules when $R$ is not a field or zero, but I am unable to construct a proof or a counterexample. Could someone provide a proof or construct a counterexample for my conjecture? If there is a counterexample, I would also like to understand how the condition on $R$ might be modified.
Edit: I already know that there are counterexamples for some R (the groups I constructed above are one of them.) What I am interested in is whether there "always" be such modules provided that $R$ is not field or zero.

@rschwieb Yes. I'm sorry that my wording was unclear. I will edit the question.

Why dont do the same as you did with $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ but replace them with arbitrary rings? I do not see right now why that should fail especially as any abelian groups are espacially  $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

@linkja If $R$ is domain, we can do what I did in groups. But in general, I think it is difficult to use the same method because $R^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ and $R^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}\oplus R/I$ can be isomorphic(e.g., $R=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ and $I=\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus2\mathbb{N}}$.)
We are also unable to use $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots]$ and $R[x_1, x_2, \ldots]/(x_1^2)$ because these two are always isomorohic as R-modules.

I don't understand the question. You have found a counterexample for abelian groups. Hence also for modules over the integers. Of course you can modify it trivially to find examples over other rings. Where is the issue?

@MartinBrandenburg I don't think it's trivial to find examples over other rings. I might be overlooking some trivial fact. If you have some idea to generalize the result on abelian groups, I would like to hear that.

It can certainly happen that $A\ncong B$.  If you take a Leavitt path algebra of type $(2,4)$, then the isomorphism $R^2\cong R^4$ gives you a surjection of $R^2\to R^3$, and you always have a surjection $R^3\to R^2$, but the theorems in the linked document, $R^3\ncong R^2$.

Thank you for your answer. The example is very interesting in that the modules are both free. But what I'm interested in is whether a counterexample exist for all ring R except for fields and zero. Do you know something about this?
